# what's the difference among row key, primary key and index in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm so confused.
When to use them and how to determine which one to use?
If a column is index/primary key/row key, could it be duplicated?

I want to create a column family to store some many-to-many info, for example, one column is the given name and the other is surname. One given name can related to many surnames, and one surname could have different given names.

I need to query surnames by a given name, and the given names by a specified surname too.

How to create the table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is a NoSQL database, and as such has no such concept of many-to-many relationships. Ideally a table should not have anything other than a primary key. In your case the right way to model it in Cassandra is to create two tables, one with name as the primary key and the other with surname as the primary key

When you need to query by either key, you need to query the table that has that key as the primary key

EDIT:
From the Cassandra docs:

> Cassandra's built-in indexes are best on a table having many rows that
>   contain the indexed value. The more unique values that exist in a
>   particular column, the more overhead you will have, on average, to
>   query and maintain the index. For example, suppose you had a races
>   table with a billion entries for cyclists in hundreds of races and
>   wanted to look up rank by the cyclist. Many cyclists' ranks will share
>   the same column value for race year. The race_year column is a good
>   candidate for an index.
>
> Do not use an index in these situations:
>
> - On high-cardinality columns for a query of a huge volume of records    for a small number of results.
> - In tables that use a counter column On a frequently updated or deleted column.
> - To look for a row in a large partition unless narrowly queried.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Two tables is a good way while we'd make sure their content are the same.  when creating a table, we can specify the primary key; after create a table we can create index for it. So it still has the concept index and primary key. When we query, the key should be the primary key or the index?

Comment: Any additional index for a table will slow down queries. When a query is executed the primary key should be queried always. You can add indexes but every index has a performance penalty

Comment: then what's the purpose and benefit of index?